# Einkaufen gehen oder shoppen gehen?

Tags: meaning, english-to-german, difference, word-choice, loanword

Wie unterscheidet man "einkaufen" und "shoppen"?

Comment: @SwissCodeMen - Technically that question doesn't count as duplicate because it's in English and this question is in German.

Comment: Hmm ok, I agree. But if that's the only hurdle: there are *translation services* ;)

Answer (score 6):

Es gibt keine klare Definition und keinen klaren Unterschied, den alle verstehen.

Manche Leute machen einen Unterschied und sagen, dass "Einkaufen" den Bedarf an Lebensmitteln und sonstigen alltäglichen Dingen betrifft. Also zum Beispiel den Einkauf im Supermarkt. Einkaufen ist dann sozusagen ein Teil der Hausarbeit wie Wäschewaschen und Putzen.

"Shopping" dagegen ist dann eine Freizeitbeschäftigung, bei der man sich z.B. mit Freundinnen trifft, in die Stadt geht, Dinge ansieht und Kleidung anprobiert, vielleicht etwas kauft, vielleicht aber auch nicht, Prosecco und Latte Macchiato schlürft und es sich gutgehen lässt.

Wie du siehst, sind das beides Stereotype, es gibt keine klare Abgrenzung, und, wie gesagt, es machen auch nicht alle diesen Unterschied.